# WCF Client Closed event not fired

Tags: c#, wcf, publish-subscribe, duplex

I have a WCF server which maintains a reference to a client callback using a duplex model.

If I explicitly close the callback connection on the server:

```
ICallBack callBack = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallBack>();
callBack.Close()
```

The client fails to receive notification of this event through subscribing to either of:

```
client.InnerChannel.Closed += Handler;
client.InnerDuplexChannel.Closed += Handler;
```

Neither event handler is executed.

However, if I change the callback to an `Abort` instead of a `Close` on the server-side, the client receives notification of the `Faulted` handler and then subsequently the `Closed` handler.  So aborting works as expected.

I've checked the callback is in a valid state so why is it the client is receiving the `Faulted` notification on `Abort` and NOT the `Closing` notification on `Close`?  The state of the callback after `Close` is `Closed`.

As per the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195520(v=vs.110).aspx) gracefully closing the callback connection using `Close` would be my preferred choice over the more abrupt `Abort`.

Answer (score 1):

because you're casting that to your own interface, which I assume implements Close( ), which is not something that will fire a WCF event.

You need to do this:

```
IClientChannel pClientChannel = (IClientChannel) callback;
pClientChannel.Close();
```

that's simplified. You really should do the try/catch Close/Abort pattern. If close doesn't work, call abort on it.